# Register through url

Tags: user-registration, wp-register-script

Im looking for a solution where you can register through an url.

Here's the thing, I want send out an email with a Url link.

Best case:
If the receiver click's on this link, the automaticly will be registered to my wordpress site (and become a subscriber) and be redirected to a page whitin my site.

Second:
...or they will be redricted to an registration page where their email id is already has been put in, so they just have to click "accept" on this page to be registered.

Is this doable at all?

Comment: Note, plugin/theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) here. Please rewrite your question to ask for a real solution, not for a link.

Comment: @toscho alright!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few possibilities.

1. When you generate the emails (I don't know how you are doing this
   but we'll skip that), register an user for each email generated.
   Then track the user logins. If, after a week or so, the user has not
   logged in, delete the user.
2. When you generate the emails, generate keys and store them in the
   `$wpdb->options` table. Your email link sends people to a page that
   checks for that key and adds users if the key is found.
3. Send people to a registration page and automatically populate the
   email address based on the URL.

Approaches #1 and #2 are problematic in that there isn't a way for users to chose their own usernames, though I suppose you could use the email address or part of it, though that undermines part of the login security system and potentially published email addresses to boot. Generated usernames will frustrate your users. I'd say they also have big potential for abuse unless you are very careful with implementation, and generate solid registration keys. These two will also be the most complicated to implement.

Option #3, is in my opinion the best of the three since 1) users can choose a username, and 2) none of the login security is compromised. The catch is that the default login page-- `login.php`-- uses `POST` which you cannot send over a link in an email so you'd need to create a page to process the link's `GET` and submit it. It is also probably the most honest of the three and the least likely to provoke a "how the *$&% did I get registered on that site?" response.